# Why are there sometimes multiple processes of a daemon in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, init.d

I noticed that there are three instances of the same daemon running on my Ubuntu system:

```
root      1167  0.0  0.0 122556  5808 ?        Ss   13:53   0:00 smbd -F
root      1371  0.0  0.0 122540  1632 ?        S    13:53   0:00 smbd -F
root      1733  0.0  0.0 125104  4704 ?        S    13:58   0:00 smbd -F
```

My question is whether this is normal and why it happens.

My other question would be, if it's not normal, where do I look to correct it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the [smbd manual](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbd.8.html);

> A session is created whenever a client requests one. ***Each client gets a copy of the server for each session.*** This copy then services all connections made by the client during that session. When all connections from its client are closed, the copy of the server for that client terminates.

In other words, there is more than one active smbd session (aka windows file sharing session) active against your linux machine, and running multiple processes is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal. This is the multi-process model which is common for Unix daemons written in C. You will also find it happening for httpd (Apache), for example. httpd in prefork mode, pre-forks some processes before any requests are even received, to avoid the fork delay when a request is actually received.